# Formatting and parsing of Date and Strings in Java

Tags: java, android

I am just starting with Java (Android) and got stuck on a Date formatting issue. 
I have a small Form where you can enter a project name and choose a Start date on a Calendar. The Startdate and Projectname gets than entered into the database, after that the pre-defined Tasks get than entered automatically into the database.

- Task 1 Due Date is Startdate,
- Task 2 is the Startdate plus x days = DueDate2,
- Task 3 is The DueDate2 plus x days = DueDate3

I have now come up with the below Sourcecode and everything works besides that I get the wrong Format of my Date. For some reason, my Format is correct in newDateStr, but when I parse it again to be a Date Object, the format changes and is than incorrect. I can't see my mistake, anyone can help?

My understanding is:

1. Set the Date format of the date entered (curFormat)
2. Set the target Date format (postFormater)
3. Parse your Date which is a String at this time, to turn it into a date Object (use curFormat)
4. Format this date to get target date format (use postFormater), now its a String again
5. Parse this again to get it back to be a date which is needed for the calendar
6. Use calendar instance, setTime(here the formated date) and add the x days
7. Format the Date to get target date format (use postFormater), now its a String again
8. Because I need a Date Object again, I have to parse it again.

   ```
   // The format of your input date string
   SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 

   // The format of your target date string
   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 

   // The calendar instance which adds a locale to the date
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

   // Parse the string (pro.getStart()) to return a Date object 
   Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(pro.getStart()); 

   // Format the Date dd-MM-yyyy
   String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);

   // Parse the string to return a Date object
   Date Startdate = postFormater.parse(newDateStr);

   while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) 
   {
       Integer delayTime = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("DelayTime"));    
   if (flag == false)
   {
       dateInString = Startdate;
       flag = true;
   }else{
       cal.setTime(dateInString);
       // add the extra days
       cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, delayTime);
       // Format the Date dd-MM-yyyy
       newDateStr =  postFormater.format(cal.getTime()); 
       // Parse the string to return a Date object
       dateInString =  postFormater.parse(newDateStr);


   Log.i("newDateStr Format",newDateStr.toString()); // 29-11-2012
   Log.i("dateInString parse",dateInString.toString()); // Thu Nov 29 00:00:00 GMT 2012
   ```

I hope someone sees my mistake. Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: are you storing the date in a string format ?

Comment: why do you format dateObj and parse it later?

Comment: pro.getStart() is a String in the format MM-dd-yyyy, I parse this to turn it into a date object to be than able to format it into the correct format dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: what i meant was dateInString is the same as dateObj, except you format and parse it in the middle.

Comment: Its the same just in the first round of the loop. Than it will change.

Comment: doesn't seems so. newDateStr is cal.getTime formatted, and the next line, dateInString is that formatted string parsed. that seems redoundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object does not have any format in it or memory of the format you used to parse it.  The output of its `toString` method, and hence what you get as output from `dateInString.toString()` will always be in the default JDK format that you are seeing: `Thu Nov 29 00:00:00 GMT 2012`

You have to use a formatter to convert it into a formatted string whenever you want to display it.  You cannot "Format the Date object" so to say.  (UI frameworks tend to have built in facilities for doing this automatically.)

Comment: I think I slowly understand the issue. Thank you for your answer and all the other answers !

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep converting the `Calendar` back to a string each time you loop. Keep one and just accumulate the delays in place...

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// Set the date once
cal.setTime(fmt.parse(pro.getStart()));

while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
    // Accumulate additional days
    Integer delayTime = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("DelayTime"));
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, delayTime);
}

String endDate = fmt.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: But the delay always gets added to the last Date. So on round 1 its the Startdate, second round Startdate plus x days, round 3 date from round 2 plus x days .... after each round cv2.put(colTaskDueDate, dateInString.toString()); than move.next and again.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem correctly. Can you please put more detail into the question.

Comment: I have add a few more information above, I hope this helps to make it more clear. Thanks for your help!